# Why doesnt HTML-form insert values into Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

So the PHP script is actually having a connection with the server, but somehow the database at localhost doesn't fill. What did I possibly do wrong?

script.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "testdb");

if (!$link) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is 
great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

$klas = isset($_POST['klasDown']);
$naam = isset($_POST['naamTxt']);

$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO resultaten (Klas, Naam) VALUES (?, ?");
if (!$stmt) {
echo "false";
} else {
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $klas, $naam);
$stmt->execute();
}


mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="script.php">
Naam: <input name="naamTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" 
id="naamTxt" class="searchField"/> <br>

Klas: <select name="klasDown">
  <option value="H4A" selected="selected">H4A</option>
  <option value="H4B" >H4B</option>
  <option value="H4C">H4C</option>
  <option value="H4C">H4D</option>
  <option value="H4C">V4A</option>
  <option value="H4C">V4B</option>
  <option value="H4C">V4C</option>
  <option value="H4C">V4D</option>  
</select> 


<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">1. Kies 1/5 </div>
<div class="col text-center"><input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_1" 
value="Helemaal mee oneens"></div>
<div class="col text-center"><input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_2" 
value="Deels oneens"></div> 
<div class="col text-center"><input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_3" 
value="Neutraal"></div> 
<div class="col text-center"><input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_4" 
value="Deels mee eens"></div> 
<div class="col text-center"><input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_5" 
value="Helemaal mee eens"></div>
</div>

<input type= "submit" style="text-align: center" 
onclick="bereken()">
</form>
```

^ Above is the Html Form

Bereken() function:

```
function bereken() {

    var e = 0;
    var c = 0;


    if(document.getElementById('v1_1').checked)  {
      c = c - 0
    }else if(document.getElementById('v1_2').checked)  {
      c += 1;
    }else if(document.getElementById('v1_3').checked)  {
      c += 2;
    }else if(document.getElementById('v1_4').checked)  {
      c += 3;
    }else if(document.getElementById('v1_5').checked){
      c += 4;
    }

    var klas = li.options[li.selectedIndex].value;
    var naam = document.getElementById('searchTxt').value;

    alert(klas + ", " + naam);
}
```

^ This is the Javascript bereken() function .
Apparently too much code, so have to add some text.

Comment: That has nothing to do with phpmyadmin.

Comment: @SLaks could you kindly explain then?

Comment: share your complete HTML form please

Comment: @RamRaider it is not the complete form as it has around 400 lines of code with radio buttons, but I hope it it not a point

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: Having read the comments below it seems the issue most likely is caused by the javascript function so the whole form is probably not needed but you should include ALL relevant code when posting a question as those that try to help are generally not mindreaders. Please update your question to include all relevant code - especially the javascript function `bereken`

Comment: @RamRaider done.

Comment: as @FelippeDuarte suggested- the javascript function doesn't actually do anything in terms of submitting the form / transmitting any data. The correct attribute for the button would be `type='submit'` rather than `action= "submit"`

Comment: actually I had already changed that in my code, but it still doesnt work

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code. You're mixing and matching styles here for no apparent reason. Try and use the newer form exclusively.

Comment: @tadman thanks for pointing that out, I am quite new to PHP, and just use it for the purpose of sending the html form to the DB, does what you say affect the problem?

Comment: Consistency is important. In programming every character can matter, and all too often a simple mistake caused by confusion or a typo can take hours or days to eliminate. Try to keep things as organized as practical, as consistent as possible, and you won't make silly mistakes like that.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$klas = isset($_POST['klasDown']);
$naam = isset($_POST['naamTxt']);
```

with

```
$klas = $_POST['klasDown'];
$naam = $_POST['naamTxt'];
```

`isset` will return a boolen, not a string that you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but now I get the messages: Notice: Undefined index: klasDown

Comment: and Notice: Undefined index: naamTxt

Comment: Where those data are supposed to come from?

Comment: From a html page with a form, I will update the question

Comment: Everything seems to be ok. Are you using a `<button type="submit">` or submitting with Ajax?

Comment: I have a button, but not with "submit": <button style="text-align: center" onclick="bereken()">Verstuur</button>

Comment: and what `bereken()` does?

Comment: It is a custom JS method that just alerts with some info

Comment: Could the cause be the missing action = "submit" ?

Comment: Does the javascript function actually submit the form?

Comment: Update your question with the code of `bereken()` function

Comment: @RamRaider no the JS code does not submit the form, I have type="submit" as another element in the button now

Comment: Still not working after you replace the button with type="submit" ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte nope, still getting 'Notice: Undefined index: klasDown'

Comment: and 'Notice: Undefined index: naamTxt'

Comment: also I get the echo 'false' on the next page when I submit the form

Answer (score 0):

On script.php do the following

If(isset($_POST['submit''])){

$klas = $_POST['klasDown'];

$naam = $_POST['naamTxt'];

$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO resultaten (Klas, Naam) VALUES (?, ?");

if (!$stmt) {

echo "false";

} else {

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $klas, $naam);

$stmt->execute();

}

}

Replace the button With the following

input type= "submit"

name="submit"

value=" Verstuur"

style="text-align: center"

onsubmit="bereken()"

Comment: Just did that, but still no records in my DB :(. The error messages like  'Notice: Undefined index: naamTxt' are gone though

Comment: just try to rename your input name and use another name

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ <- should this get the same name then?

Comment: Follow The following example and apply 100% works <form id="myForm" method="post" action="index.php">
Naam: <input name="naamTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="naamTxt" class="searchField"/> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
If(isset($_POST['submit'])){


echo $naam = $_POST['naamTxt']; 
}
?>

Comment: just copy and test

Comment: to proceed with your login add onsubmit <input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="bereken()">

Comment: Sorry Hamis I dont really understand it, could you please provide a more complete answer?

Comment: Undefined index: naamTxt, this error is on php or ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152639/discussion-between-hamis-juma-and-user3660293).

Comment: No I meant that that error message is gone now, but I still dont see the records in mysql

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following might prove of use in getting the database updated. The javascript function itself now submits the form ( based upon original idea ) and by doing so allows you to use an `alert` statement with the values to be sent. I was initially getting an error about undefined `li` in the javascript function - hence using `querySelector` to identify the form element.

In this instance the form submits to the same page but the form action could easily be set as you had previously, I only did this to write the code now. The sql uses prepared statements - not tested but should(?!) be OK.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        try{

            $dbuser='root';
            $dbpwd='';
            $dbhost='localhost';
            $dbname='testdb';

            $link=new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


            if( !$link ) {
                $message=sprintf( "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.\nDebugging errno: %s\nDebugging error: %s" );
                throw new Exception( $message, $link->errno, $link->error );
            }

            $klas = !empty( $_POST['klasDown'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'klasDown', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : false;
            $naam = !empty( $_POST['naamTxt'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'naamTxt', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : false;

            if( !$klas ) throw new Exception('klas cannot be empty');
            if( !$naam ) throw new Exception('naam cannot be empty');

            $stmt = $link->prepare( "insert into `resultaten` (`klas`, `naam`) values ( ?, ? )" );
            if( $stmt ){

                $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $klas, $naam );
                $result=$stmt->execute();
                if( !$result )throw new Exception('SQL insert failed');

            } else {
                throw new Exception('Failed to prepare SQL query');
            }


            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            $link->close();

        }catch( Exception $e ){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bereken</title>
        <script>

            function bereken() {
                var e = 0;
                var c = 0;

                if(document.getElementById('v1_1').checked)  {
                  c = c - 0
                }else if(document.getElementById('v1_2').checked)  {
                  c += 1;
                }else if(document.getElementById('v1_3').checked)  {
                  c += 2;
                }else if(document.getElementById('v1_4').checked)  {
                  c += 3;
                }else if(document.getElementById('v1_5').checked){
                  c += 4;
                }
                var li=document.querySelector('select[name="klasDown"]')
                var klas = li.options[li.selectedIndex].value;
                var naam = document.getElementById('naamTxt').value;

                alert( klas + ", " + naam );
                document.forms['myForm'].submit();
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" method="post">
            Naam: <input name="naamTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="naamTxt" class="searchField"/> <br>

            Klas: <select name="klasDown">
              <option value="H4A" selected="selected">H4A</option>
              <option value="H4B" >H4B</option>
              <option value="H4C">H4C</option>
              <option value="H4C">H4D</option>
              <option value="H4C">V4A</option>
              <option value="H4C">V4B</option>
              <option value="H4C">V4C</option>
              <option value="H4C">V4D</option> 
            </select> 


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">1. Kies 1/5 </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_1" value="Helemaal mee oneens">
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_2" value="Deels oneens">
                </div> 
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_3" value="Neutraal">
                </div> 
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_4" value="Deels mee eens">
                </div> 
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_5" value="Helemaal mee eens">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" style="text-align: center" onclick="bereken()">Verstuur</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the php file now engaged?

Comment: You could copy the php to a new file `script.php` and set the form action as you had originally. I only put it all in one document like this for convenience when writing the code.